# UBIFS going into Read only mode

Tags: linux-kernel, readonly, flash-memory, corruption, ubifs

I have a customer unit having UBIFS file system on it. Unit is up and running fine. The unit under goes a test of power cycling (AC mode-Battery mode- AC mode). At some point of time the unit(UBIFS file system) becomes read only.

1. Does the power cycling test causing this issue?
2. If UBIFS file system becomes 100% full, does this cause the issue?

What are the possible root causes for Read Only condition? Is this a preventive measure from kernel itself?

This issue is not seen in all units with same set of test environment. Whether the particular hardware can also cause the issue?

Comment: Does your UBIFS stay read-only forever (e.g., also after a clean reboot)? I suspect the AC-battery-AC cycling could have cause corruption, which perhaps UBIFS could not recover from.

Comment: No, it comes back to normal(R/W mode) after a clean reboot...

Comment: Even after the unit comes back to RW mode, again it goes to Read only mode some time later. The unit has a mechanism to identify Read only condition and initiates a system reboot. But it last for some time only and again unit turns to be read only.